# Corner radius of a UIButton in UICollectionViewCell not working

Tags: iphone, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView in a ViewController of type ANY-ANY storyboard and using auto-layout with swift. I have changed the size of ViewController to iPhone 5 screen size.

The problem is that, there is a button inside the UICollectionViewCell and I am trying to make that circular. When I run in iPhone 5 the button gets in circular fine, But if I run in iPhone 6 or 6+ it doesn't come in circular.

Below is the code i am using in "cellForItemAtIndexPath"

```
    var btnImage = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as UIButton
    btnImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btnImage.layer.cornerRadius = btnImage.frame.size.height/2
```

The result of this code is as below 
[image]

And if I use below code

```
    var btnImage = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as UIButton
    btnImage.layoutIfNeeded()
    btnImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btnImage.layer.cornerRadius = btnImage.frame.size.height/2
```

The result is as below

[image]

Does anyone have any Idea about this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution that worked for this issue is below:

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds //This is important line
var btnImage = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as UIButton
btnImage.layoutIfNeeded() //This is important line
btnImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
btnImage.layer.cornerRadius = btnImage.frame.size.height/2
```

Above code makes the button complete circular.

Answer (score 1):

Roundrect not working with collection view cell can not be the case. I have just created a demo application to test that and it works. Below is code from my demo.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell:CollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.roundTestButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.roundTestButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

    println(cell.roundTestButton)

    return cell
}
```

Or [here is git link](https://github.com/rptwsthi/SwiftTraining.git) of complete project.

Comment: I wanted to make the button complete circular. I downloaded your code from git and replaced the line with "        cell.roundTestButton.layer.cornerRadius = cell.roundTestButton.frame.size.height/2
"
and run on iPhone 6+ and that was not complete circle, rather it became oval.

Comment: @TeenanathPaul I didn't worked on making it circular I just made sure that round rect work perfect fine on UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: Thanks @rptwsthi, I got the solution, and the button is now complete circular.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to autolayout constraint. As the height and width can increased after corner radius size is set.Try to set this in storyboard.